# wrap python with statement from 2 classes in a single class

Tags: python, with-statement

I have a python class A with `with` statement and class B with `with` statement. Now it works like:

```
with A() as a:
    with B() as b:
        do_things()
```

How can I build a class C that wrap class A and class B so that I can call it like:

```
 with C() as c:
        do_things()
```

has the identical funtions

Comment: `C` must become a context manager, meaning it implements some special methods. Specification is in [PEP 343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/#specification-the-with-statement)

Comment: Note that you can also do `with A() as a, B as b:` and avoid double nesting in python3, if you are in python2 you can use [`contextlib.nested`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.nested). In python3.3 there is [`ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack) which might be useful. If you actually want to have your own class then you just need to implement `__enter__` and `__exit__` method accordingly.

Comment: Right, c = (a, b)

Comment: @Bakuriu: You can also use `with A() as a, B() as b:` in Python 2.7. `contextlib.nested` is error-prone and should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: @user2357112 I did not say python2.7 but python2. Unfortunately some people are still using python2.6 or less for some legacy systems (me included)....

Comment: @Bakuriu: [`contextlib2`](https://pypi.org/project/contextlib2/) still supports 2.6, and it has `ExitStack`, so that's a safer option if you can get the dependency approved.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to suggest an alternative. You can initialise both `a` and `b` on the same line:

```
with A() as a, B() as b:
    do_things()
```

This is more concise and reduces the amount of indentation in deeply nested code.

However, if you absolutely must use a class, then override the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods:

```
class C:
    def __enter__(self):
        self._a = A()
        self._b = B()
        return (self._a.__enter__(), self._b.__enter__())

    def __exit__(self ,type, value, traceback):
        # Cleanup code here.
        self._b.__exit__(type, value, traceback)
        self._a.__exit__(type, value, traceback)
```

And then use `C` inside a context manager like this:

```
with C() as (a, b):
    do_things()
```

If you don't want to reference `a` and `b`, or if you don't plan on doing anything with them, then

```
with C():
    do_things()
```

Will also work. This should be enough to get started, but please note there are drawbacks as kindly mentioned by users in the comments. The main one being that if `self._b.__enter__` throws errors, `self._a.__enter__` will need to be cleaned up (this can be done using try-except-finally). Furthermore, some context managers may need to be treated differently based on what resource is being managed.

Comment: Your `__enter__` method exits the `a` and `b` context managers.

Comment: @user2357112 Thank you and good point... I am not sure how to get around that.

Comment: That doesn't look quite right. You'd probably want to delegate both the enter and exit methods explicitly in C.

Comment: Return a.__enter__(), b.__enter__()

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks! I think that should fix it... let me know if something's missing still.

Comment: Somewhat better, but `self._a` doesn't get cleaned up if `self._b.__enter__` encounters an error. Also, it may be worth mentioning that some context managers only need to be cleaned up if they're actually entered, while some (like open files) need to be cleaned up if they're created at all.

Comment: For C to have the same methods, it should extend A and B

Comment: Shouldn't the `__exit__`s be called in reverse order?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem you're right, it slipped my mind... thanks.

Comment: @coldspeed: and to make things worse, if `__exit__` returns a "truthful" value, that means the exception is surpressed, and the `__exit__` itself can generate an exception, which is then passed to the "outer" context manager.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Like I mentioned, this was a basic prototype only to get the OP thinking. It does not handle many of the corner cases and exceptions that you and the other commenters mentioned can happen. I have made sure to add a footnote about those dangers already. :)

Comment: @coldspeed: well, a +1 is well deserved :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks! Even more so for you, returned.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer**: it is *possible*. But context-managers allow to implement some logic, which makes it "tricky" to implemented it exactly the right way. Below you see a "Proof of Concept", but I do not guarantee that it has *exactly* the same behavior. Therefore I really advise to work with nested `with`s.

**What is not covered here**: the `__init__`, or `__enter__` can raise exceptions as well, and these are then handled by the "outer" context managers. This makes it of course rather complicated. You basically would need to "build" a stack in the `__enter__`, and then "pop" the stack in case one of the `__enter__`s fails. This scenario is *not* covered here.

We can make a "composite" context manager:

```
class C:

    def __init__(self, *ctxs):
        self.ctxs = ctxs

    def __enter__(self):
        return tuple(ctx.__enter__() for ctx in self.ctxs)

    def __exit__(self, self, exception_type, exception_value, traceback):
        for ctx in reversed(self.ctxs):
            try:
                if ctx.__exit__(exception_type, exception_value, traceback):
                    (exception_type, exception_value, traceback) = (None,) * 3
            except Exception as e:
                exception_value = e
                traceback = e.__traceback__
                exception_type = type(e)
        return exception_value is None
```

The `__exit__` part is tricky. First of all, we need to exit in *reverse* order. But the exception handling is even more complicated: if an `__exit__` silenced an exception, by returning a "truthful" value, then we should pass `(None, None, None)` as `(exception_type, exeption_value, traceback)`, but a problem that can occur is that an `__exit__` on the other hand triggers an exception itself, and thus then introduces a new exception.

We can then use the context processor like:

```
with C(A(), B()) as (a,b):
    # ...
    pass
```

The above thus allows to implement a context manager for an arbitrary number of "sub-contextmanagers". We can subclass this to generate a specific one, like:

```
class ContextAB(C):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ContextAB, self).__init__(A(), B())
```

and then use this as:

```
with ContextAB() as (a, b):
    # ...
    pass
```

But long story short: use nested `with` statements. It also makes it more explicit what is going on here. Right now the `C` encapsulate all sorts of logic, which are better made explicit. If *entering* `B` fails, then this should result in an exception that is handled by the `__exit__` of `A`, etc. This makes it very cumbersome to get the "details" completely equivalent to the semantics of the `with` statement.

Comment: This is basically a reimplementation of [`contextlib.nested`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.nested), with the same error-prone quirks that led to the removal of `contextlib.nested` in Python 3, particularly the failure to clean up earlier context managers if later context managers fail in `__init__` or `__enter__`.

Comment: @user2357112: well I definitely agree this is not a good idea. And you are correct that there is indeed some extra work to check if the `__init__` or `__enter__` fails.

Answer (score 1):

If your reason for doing this is to reduce indentation or merge the `with` statements, you don't need to. You can just do

```
with A() as a, B() as b:
    ...
```

entering multiple context managers on a single line.

If your `C` has other reasons to exist, you need to be careful about handling the case where one context manager fails after another context manager has been created and/or entered. [`contextlib.ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack) can help you implement this robustly, or [`contextlib2.ExitStack`](https://pypi.org/project/contextlib2/) if you're still on Python 2:

```
import contextlib

class C(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
            stack.enter_context(A())
            stack.enter_context(B())
            self._stack = stack.pop_all()
        return self
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb):
        return self._stack.__exit__(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
```